# Laravel 4 how to link to destroy and what is the function name

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a controller in the admin directory with following routes

```
Route::controller('attachments','AdminAttachmentsController');
```

now i want to create a delete link using javascript so my url look like

```
http://localhost/project_name/public/admin/attachments/delete/1
```

and in my controller i have right the following code

```
public function delete($id)
{
    die("i m here");
}
```

but when i hit the delete link its always show that "Controller method not found."

please tell me what is the function name for delete and what url i call

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can see your active routes by running:

`php artisan routes`

That being said, the resource controller [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) have the full list of all paths, actions and their route names generated by `Route::controller()`

You should also note that the routes generated via `Route::controller` expect controller method names to be prefixed with their respective HTTP verb. Right now your router expects requests to `DELETE ...//{}` because your controller method only defines the verb but not the path name. You should change your method name to `deleteDelete($id)`.

Comment: i have run the command and its show the routes and i check in that i found followig lines

DELETE admin/attachments//{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}
|      | AdminAttachmentsController@delete            | admin-auth


and  

 GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE admin/attachments/{_missing}
 |      | AdminAttachmentsController@missingMethod     | admin-auth

now i create the following function function delete() {} and in the URL 

http://localhost/project_name/public/admin/attachments/1

but error still the same

Comment: @DeepakGoyal you are not hitting the right path; I updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: i also use this but same error please tell me which path i should hit like "http://localhost/project_name/public/admin/attachments/delete/1" and what function name should i declare in the controlller

Comment: @DeepakGoyal you either need to hit "localhost/project_name/public/admin/attachments//1" or change your route name to "deleteDelete". And in either scenario you have to make sure that you are making a DELETE request not GET.

Comment: please tell me by which name i create the function and for request i am using jQuery after confirmain i use wondow.location.href = URL and than thi hit th URL which i  mention in the question so please tell me which function name function function_name() {} and the url so that it works